# from Langevin to Fokker-Planck

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to get the Fokker-Planck equation for the Langevin equation
$$\ddot x + a(t)\dot x + b(t)x = F(t) + \eta (t)$$
($\eta (t)$ is random fluctuatin). I know how to get it for the simple case, like $$\ddot x + \alpha \dot x + V'(x) = \eta (t)$$
where $\alpha $ is constant. But I haven't got any ideas, how to get it in the case witch variable coefficients.
Can someone help me?
Many thanks for any help.
P.S.Sorry for my terrible English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant $F(t)$ is deterministic forcing, and $\eta(t)$ is standard Gaussian white noise. In that case, explicit time dependence does not pose any additional complexity. You can simply rewrite the Langevin equation to canonical Ito SDE form, and then write the Fokker-Planck PDE from there. Details below.

$$\text{Let}\: \begin{pmatrix} x_{1}\\ x_{2}\end{pmatrix} := \begin{pmatrix} x\\ \dot{x}\end{pmatrix}. \quad \text{Ito SDE:}\,\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}x_{1}(t)\\ \mathrm{d}x_{2}(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_{2}\\ -a(t)x_{2} - b(t)x_{1} + F(t)\end{pmatrix} \mathrm{d}t \: + \: \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}W(t),$$

where $\mathrm{d}W(t) = \eta(t)\mathrm{d}t$. Then the Fokker-Planck PDE for joint density $f(x_{1}(t), x_{2}(t); t)$ is given by

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = - x_{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}} + \left(a(t)x_{2} + b(t)x_{1} - F(t)\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}} + a(t)f + \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}^{2}}.$$